# A subset of the second Baire category on the real line

Tags: baire-category, the-baire-space

Why is the subset in $\mathbb{R}$ of the second Baire category uncountable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any countable set is  a countable union of singleton sets and singleton sets are nowhere dense.

Comment: stupid enough question from me, thanks for the answer